# Shopify Liquid: Remove all products added to Cart Page after "OnClick" Submit Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid

I have custom Submit Button and I want to remove all Products was Added in Cart Page once I clicking on this Submit button:

`<button class="button_get order_button btn btn-pink js_submit button__text orderButton" id="send" type="submit">Submit</button>`

Thank you for your time & help!

Comment: This comment just to re-rank the post to find someone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

Send a request to `/cart/clear` e.g.

```
<button onclick="clearCart();">Clear cart</button>
<script>
function clearCart() {
    var xhrClearCart = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrClearCart.open('POST', '/cart/clear.js', true);
    xhrClearCart.onload = alert("Cart is empty!");
    xhrClearCart.send();  
}
</script>
```